# Ошибка при парсинге: list index out of range

Tags: python, парсер, cssselect

Всем здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь выкачать ссылки и информацию по ним с основной страницы хабры. Вытащить сами ссылки получается, но когда пытаюсь сделать то же с текстом, выдает:

> list index out of range.

Попробовал проверить URL, так вообще ничего не выводит. Выглядит странно, помогите разобраться. Спасибо.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from lxml.html import fromstring

URL = 'https://habrahabr.ru'
ITEM_PATH = '.post__header .post__title_link'
DESCRIBE_PATH = '.content html_format'

def parse_cources():
    f = urlopen( URL )
    list_html = f.read().decode( 'utf-8' )
    list_doc = fromstring(list_html)


    for elem in list_doc.cssselect(ITEM_PATH):
        a = elem.cssselect('a')[0]
        href = a.get('href')
        name = a.text
        details_html = urlopen(URL).read().decode('utf-8')
        details_doc = fromstring(details_html)
        descr_elem = details_doc.cssselect(DESCRIBE_PATH)[0]

        '''
        if URL in details_doc:
            descr_elem = details_doc.cssselect(DESCRIBE_PATH)[0]
            print(descr_elem.text_content())
        else: continue
        '''

        print(descr_elem.text_content())


def main():
    parse_cources()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас не корректно задан `DESCRIBE_PATH`, поэтому вам возвращается пустой список.

Попробуйте задать `DESCRIBE_PATH` вот так:

```
DESCRIBE_PATH = "div[class='content html_format']"
```

После вызова:

```
descr_elem = details_doc.cssselect(DESCRIBE_PATH)
```

Вам вернется список из 10 `Element`.